# Automation test with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, web, automation

I have 1 problem. I open a page (referred to as tab 1) and then click the Facebook button on that page. Screen redirect to the Facebook sign-in page (known as tab 2). I tried using the get url of tab 2 function, but it only returned the url for tab 1. I do not believe that I am switching to tab 2. then, how do you fix it? I greatly appreciate it.

I want to get url of tab2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to new window then try to get the URL.

```
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String eachwindow: windows)
    {
        if(!eachwindow.equals(parentWindow))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(eachwindow);
        }
    }
    
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println(url);
```